Mobile with telepathic power, teen lives his fantasies
I saw a movie like American Pie, where there's a high school teen whose mobile phone gets telepathic persuasive powers, after a lightning strikes his girlfriend's similar themed science project and his mobile phone lying in close proximity, which leads to the above mentioned powers.
Then once the teen discovers the powers that have befell on his mobile, he starts living the typical teen fantasies, mostly involving sex.
All this guy has to do is call the person and instruct him over the phone, and the person called does exactly as said.
Have been searching various keywords combinations but couldnt find it.
PS: AFAIK it was an American or maybe from any western country dubbed in English, wasn't too old, felt like made within last 10 - 12 years. No famous actor(ess).   

Details like language\country & approximate year would help. BTW, French teen comedy Hellphone from 2007, about a teen coming into possession of a mobile that can control people, is very similar, but it's not due to an accident, the phone's just demonic.

I feel the details added, while rough, meet the requirements to not close this question.

@MattD ... yup. I think there is more than enough detail to figure it out. We've seen quite a few other ITM questions with far less detail (even with more words).

OK, so this appears to be the 2007 sex comedy Pretty Cool Too, the sequel to Pretty Cool from 2006. From an online synopsis:

nerdy kid Walter (Eric Fagundes) lives next door to a nerdy girl Agatha (Julia Lehman) and to a reality television show house which houses 5 PlayPen girls. His parents give him a new phone called Genie (original, eh), which after a freak lightning storm, can control the actions of people. Of course after learning of this power, Walter uses it for his own selfish purposes — mainly getting girls naked.

The trailer (careful: raunchy) is available here.

yup this is it.. Thanks bro.
